# Compare a data-frame column is between another two columns of different data-frame

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

Have Two data frame as below .

```
print(Data)



Band         CGI       CID   
  3G  0-0-1505-37226   1505 
  3G   0-0-111-14769    111 
  3G  0-0-1505-36896   1505 
  3G  0-0-1501-33532   1501 
  3G   0-0-111-14769    111 
 ...             ...    ... 
  3G    0-0-111-4857    111 
  3G  0-0-1505-37458   1505 
  3G   0-0-222-43029    222 
  3G   0-0-222-43029    222 
  3G   0-0-222-43029    222 

print(IDS)

Circle STARTR  ENDR
 KUM    601   622  
 BMF   1401  1406  
 KIL      2  1215  
 LOK    206   226  
 HOE   1101  1108  
 HOP    401   403  
 KOK    501   503  
 KRR    801   817  
 KUJ   1301  1303  
 KJL    101   153  
CPGJ    301   339  
 BNG    701   714  
 JHG   1501  1507  
 EMG    701   911  
 WPR   1001  1014
```

Requirement is to find out the Circle from IDS data where the CID is present in Data frame is in between STARTR and ENDR.

final out put will be .

```
Band             CGI  CID   Circle
  3G  0-0-1505-37226   1505 JHG   
  3G   0-0-111-14769    111 KJL   
  3G  0-0-1505-36896   1505 JHG   
  3G  0-0-1501-33532   1501 JHG   
  3G   0-0-111-14769    111 KJL   
 ...             ...    ... ...   
  3G    0-0-111-4857    111 KJL   
  3G  0-0-1505-37458   1505 JHG   
  3G   0-0-222-43029    222 LOK 
  3G   0-0-222-43029    222 LOK   
  3G   0-0-222-43029    222 LOK   




 Data['Circle'] = np.where((Data['CID'] >= IDS['STARTR']) & (Data['CID'] <= IDS['ENDR']),IDS['Circle'],np.nan)
```

have tried lot of options but no luck . 
sample error is ..
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: Can the several intervals defined by `STARTR` and `ENDR` in `ISD` overlap? How the output would look if a `CID` is found to be in more than one interval?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do using `.apply`:

```
# get matching circles
Data['Circle'] = Data['CID'].apply(lambda x: IDS.loc[(IDS['STARTR'] <= x) & (x <= IDS['ENDR']),'Circle'].values)

  Band             CGI   CID      Circle
0   3G  0-0-1505-37226  1505       [JHG]
1   3G   0-0-111-14769   111  [KIL, KJL]
2   3G  0-0-1505-36896  1505       [JHG]
3   3G  0-0-1501-33532  1501       [JHG]
4   3G   0-0-111-14769   111  [KIL, KJL]
5   3G    0-0-111-4857   111  [KIL, KJL]
6   3G  0-0-1505-37458  1505       [JHG]
7   3G   0-0-222-43029   222  [KIL, LOK]
8   3G   0-0-222-43029   222  [KIL, LOK]
9   3G   0-0-222-43029   222  [KIL, LOK]


# get last value
Data['Circle'] = Data['Circle'].str[-1]

  Band             CGI   CID Circle
0   3G  0-0-1505-37226  1505    JHG
1   3G   0-0-111-14769   111    KJL
2   3G  0-0-1505-36896  1505    JHG
3   3G  0-0-1501-33532  1501    JHG
4   3G   0-0-111-14769   111    KJL
5   3G    0-0-111-4857   111    KJL
6   3G  0-0-1505-37458  1505    JHG
7   3G   0-0-222-43029   222    LOK
8   3G   0-0-222-43029   222    LOK
9   3G   0-0-222-43029   222    LOK
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your response , however its showing below error.   pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Comment: umm that's strange because I tested the solution. Is any of your dfs (IDS, Data) has index set ?

Comment: Hi , yes its working but the result is duplicate  ( KIL,101-153 and JHG,1501-1507) and the result showing 1505 JHG and 111 JHG

Comment: Hi YOLO, Thank you very much for your support , now its coming as required .

Answer (score 0):

[numpy where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is the wrong tool here, I guess. It is used when you need to compare arrays elementwise, but this is not your case: for each row in `Data`, you need to pick the correct row in `IDS`. Which may be more than one: looking at your exsample, your `'STARTR'` and `'ENDR'` can overlap, and in some cases according to your description you may need to pick two `Circle`s.

Here is a working solution using [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
def search(x):
    res = IDS.loc[(x >= IDS['STARTR']) & (x <= IDS['ENDR'])]['Circle']
    return list(res)

data['Circle'] = data['CID'].apply(search)
```

This returns:

```
  Band             CGI   CID      Circle
0   3G  0-0-1505-37226  1505       [JHG]
1   3G   0-0-111-14769   111  [KIL, KJL]
2   3G  0-0-1505-36896  1505       [JHG]
3   3G  0-0-1501-33532  1501       [JHG]
4   3G   0-0-111-14769   111  [KIL, KJL]
5   3G    0-0-111-4857   111  [KIL, KJL]
6   3G  0-0-1505-37458  1505       [JHG]
7   3G   0-0-222-43029   222  [KIL, LOK]
8   3G   0-0-222-43029   222  [KIL, LOK]
9   3G   0-0-222-43029   222  [KIL, LOK]
```

As you see I used a list for `Circle` column since there may be multiple values.
In your expected output seems you always pick the last one, so if this is the rule, jus replace the last line of the `search` function with:

```
return list(res)[-1]
```

and you'll get:

```
  Band             CGI   CID Circle
0   3G  0-0-1505-37226  1505    JHG
1   3G   0-0-111-14769   111    KJL
2   3G  0-0-1505-36896  1505    JHG
3   3G  0-0-1501-33532  1501    JHG
4   3G   0-0-111-14769   111    KJL
5   3G    0-0-111-4857   111    KJL
6   3G  0-0-1505-37458  1505    JHG
7   3G   0-0-222-43029   222    LOK
8   3G   0-0-222-43029   222    LOK
9   3G   0-0-222-43029   222    LOK
```

#### EDIT

To consider the cases where no `Circle` is found in the given range, you could wrap the `return` statement in a `try except` block:

```
try:
    return list(res)[-1]
except IndexError:
    return ""
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response , it almost resolved my problem , it took almost 3 to 5 minutes to give the output .  while im applying  "return list(res)[-1] "  showing IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That is probably because in your real data you have some cases where there is no `Circle` inside the range. I'll edit my answer to consider this case.